# Piecewise-constant density estimation

Tags: estimation, density-function

I came across the term "piecewise-constant density estimation" in a paper and haven't been able to find a definition for it online or in my textbook resources.  No example was given in the paper either.  Can someone define it for me?  Perhaps give an example of how it's used?  From the name, it sounds like a histogram is created with each bin's height being set to some constant value.

Comment: I think you're absolutely correct.  This sounds like a normalized histogram.  What paper was this?  Does the context suggest otherwise?  Often there are much nicer density estimators.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of density estimators that are piecewise constant.

The scaled histogram is the most obvious:

[image]

(the scaling is to make the total area 1, so that it estimates the underlying density; here I did it in R using the `freq=FALSE` argument).

But for example, there's also the kernel density estimator with a uniform kernel.

[image]

[The plot isn't perfectly accurate -- the true estimate is actually a step function, but the function `density` only evaluates it at a small set of points and uses linear interpolation between them (which works well with smooth kernels), leading it to look 'sloped' rather than stepped]

We don't have any way to tell here which (or whether) one of these was the intention in the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Say,

$$f_X(x) = \cases {0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; x<0\\
\\
0.5 \;\;\;\; 0\leq x \leq 0.4 \\
\\
2.0 \;\;\;\; 0.4 < x \leq 0.6 \\
\\
0.4 \;\;\;\; 0.6< x \leq 1.6\\
\\
0 \;\;\;\;  x > 1.6\\}
$$